# Como ejecutar dos métodos en forma simultanea

Tags: android

Como puedo hacer para que se ejecuten estos dos métodos en forma simultanea al cumplirse la condición if ,por ejemplo el método startAlert y el método servicio.

Código :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarma);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            startAlert();  //*** Aquí!!!

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

}

public void startAlert() {

    String hora_sistema = getHora("HH:mm:"); //Obtenida con el método
    String horaTuya = "23:21:";

    int timeInSec = 2;

    if (horaTuya.equals(hora_sistema)) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (timeInSec * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "La alarma sonará en " + timeInSec + " segundos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    servicio();
}
public void servicio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //first run of alarm is immediate // aranca la palicacion
    int intervalMillis = 1 * 3 * 1000; //3 segundos
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);

}
```

Comment: Se tienen que ejecutar a la vez? has pensado en hacerlo con hilos? Así cada hilo puede ejecutar un método y hacerlo a la vez

Comment: Excelente idea ,como lo podría hacer por hilos.

Comment: Aquí tienes una guía muy sencilla que explica el uso de hilos. Pruébalo y si tienes alguna duda con su uso puedes hacer otra pregunta. http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/tareas-en-segundo-plano-en-android-i-thread-y-asynctask/

Comment: Vale ,voy a analizarlo,muchas gracias.